# How to quit/exit from file included in the terminal

Tags: julia

What can I do within a file `"example.jl"` to exit/return from a call to  `include()` in the command line

```
julia> include("example.jl")
```

without existing julia itself. `quit()` will just terminate julia itself.

Edit: For me this would be useful while interactively developing code, for example to include a test file and return from the execution to the julia prompt when a certain condition is met or do only compile the tests I am currently working on without reorganizing the code to much.

Comment: Can you explain in detail what the actual problem your trying to solve is? We can probably provide better answers if you do, since it doesn't sound like you're using `include` as intended.

Comment: You could raise an exception with `error` or `throw`.

Comment: I originally had exception as part of my answer but I removed it. I think that is (probably) a butchering of the `try..catch` control path ... perhaps, with more detail, that might be a more reasonable solution however.

Comment: Raising an exception is a good idea because it breaks out to the right level. It would be nice to do the same without abusing the exception control path, but that is working for me.

Comment: I used `error("stopping")` successfully to get out of the execution of the script without exiting the julia environment as @VincentZoonekynd, recommends.

Comment: This is something I comonly need, where I have a julia_script.jl file that roughly does what I need for the moment but also has snippets of broken code that I want to keep for reference as a notebook.  I would normally put an `exit(420)` ahead of those things, which works from a shell call, but from the REPL it boots me out of the REPL as well as terminate the script.  The throw/error approach is good, but it sends a stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kristoffer will not love it, but

```
stop(text="Stop.") = throw(StopException(text))

struct StopException{T}
    S::T
end

function Base.showerror(io::IO, ex::StopException, bt; backtrace=true)
    Base.with_output_color(get(io, :color, false) ? :green : :nothing, io) do io
        showerror(io, ex.S)
    end
end
```

will give a nice, less alarming message than just throwing an error.

```
julia> stop("Stopped. Reason: Converged.")
ERROR: "Stopped. Reason: Converged."
```

Source: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/a-julia-equivalent-to-rs-stop/36568/12

Comment: This is actually the best I have found so far. I have been using error or `throw`, but the stack trace is really jarring.

Comment: This actually still provides a stack trace, though just one line: `ERROR: LoadError: "Stop."
in expression starting at /path/to/file/julia-script.jl:51`. Still, pretty good thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking to do, but it sounds like you might be better off writing your code as a function, and use a `return` to exit. You could even call the function in the include.

Comment: If the function was called from another function, it will return control to the function further up, without actually proceeding to stop executing statements causing a genuine error possibly .

Comment: The question is about running .jl files from the REPL, with breaks from arbitrary points.

Answer (score 1):

You have a latent need for a debugging workflow in Julia.  If you use `Revise.jl` and `Rebugger.jl` you can do exactly what you are asking for.

You can put in a breakpoint and step into code that is in an included file.

If you include a file from the julia prompt that you want tracked by `Revise.jl`, you need to use `includet(`.

The keyboard shortcuts in `Rebugger` let you iterate and inspect variables and modify code and rerun it from within an included file with real values.

`Revise` lets you reload functions and modules without needing to restart a julia session to pick up the changes.

https://timholy.github.io/Rebugger.jl/stable/

https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/

The combination is very powerful and is described deeply by Tim Holy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SU0SmQnnGys

https://youtu.be/KuM0AGaN09s?t=515

Note that there are some limitations with Revise, such as it doesn't reset global variables, so if you are using some global count or something, it won't reset it for the next run through or when you go back into it.  Also it isn't great with `runtests.jl` and the `Test` package.  So as you develop with Revise, when you are done, you move it into your `runtests.jl`.

Also the Juno IDE (Atom + `uber-juno` package) has good support for code inspection and running line by line and the debugging has gotten some good support lately.  I've used Rebugger from the julia prompt more than from the Juno IDE.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is good. However this is a very heavy weight solution to something meant to be very casual in the questioners use-case. And mine, that's why I like @mschauer own answer.

Answer (score 0):

@DanielArndt is right.

It's just create a dummy function in your include file and put all the code inside (except other functions and variable declaration part that will be place before). So you can use `return` where you wish. The variables that only are used in the local context can stay inside dummy function. Then it's just call the new function in the end.

Suppose that the previous code  is:

```
function func1(...)
....
end

function func2(...)
....
end

var1 = valor1
var2 = valor2
localVar = valor3  
1st code part
# I want exit here! 
2nd code part
```

Your code will look like this:

```
var1 = valor1
var2 = valor2

function func1(...)
....
end

function func2(...)
....
end


function dummy()    
  localVar = valor3  
  1st code part
  return  # it's the last running line! 
  2nd code part 
end 

dummy()
```

Other possibility is placing the top variables inside a function with a `global` prefix.

```
function dummy()    
  global var1 = valor1
  global var2 = valor2
  ...
end
```

That global variables can be used inside auxiliary function (static scope) and outside in the `REPL`

Another variant only declares the variables and its posterior use is free

```
function dummy()    
  global var1, var2
  ... 
end
```